# Passing std::vector<std::string> as array of C-style strings (char**)

Tags: c++, opengl, c++11

I'd like to pass a vector of std::strings to OpenGL as array of C-style null terminated character arrays (const char**).

```
void glTransformFeedbackVaryings(GLuint program,
                                 GLsizei count,
                                 const char **varyings,
                                 GLenum bufferMode);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Convert each of the strings using string.c_str()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First use `std::string`'s `.c_str()` function to map them to `const char*`'s.

```
std::vector<const char*> c_strs;
std::transform(std::begin(strings), std::end(strings), 
               std::back_inserter(c_strs), std::mem_fn(&std::string::c_str));
```

Then pass it to your function via the `.data()` member of vector:

```
glTransformFeedbackVaryings( ... , c_strs.size(), c_strs.data(), ...);
```

replacing the ...'s with your other parameters. Note: I haven't compiled this code, but it should be fine (in theory.)

If space is really important to you, you can reserve space in the vector ahead of time with

```
c_strs.reserve(strings.size());
```

or after the transform with

```
c_strs.shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: To complement your excellent summary, it would be: `glTransformFeedbackVaryings (..., strings.size (), c_strs.data (), ...);` the `count` parameter is the number of null-terminated strings contained in the `char**`, and this is given by the size of the strings vector.

Comment: Propably worth adding c_strs.reserve(strings.size()); ?

Comment: It probably is. That or calling `shrink_to_fit` afterwards.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman thank you. I updated my answer (and learned a bit about the api in question :))

Comment: I thought of reserve more in terms of performance than in size, because with it only a single allocation is needed. Without the vector is propably resized/reallocated during push_back.

Comment: This is true. Though it will come down to implementations. Calling reserve is a good idea though, regardless.

Comment: It is especially good when your vector grows beyond 4 KiB in size. A lot of memory allocators place memory blocks in different locations based on the requested size to reduce fragmentation, if you know ahead of time that it is going to be > 4 KiB (a very common boundary case, 16 KiB is another) you can avoid having your memory radically relocated when it grows by reserving the appropriate block size.

Answer (score 2):

The structures are too different. A std::string contains more than just a pointer, so it won't map directly to a char**.

You will need to copy the string's c_str() value into a new std::vector. Then you can pass that new vector's .data pointer to OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<const char*> arr;
for(auto&& str:vec)
  arr.push_back(str.c_str());

foo(...,arr.data(),...);
```

the above, if `vec` is your vector of `std::string`, will call `foo` with a `char const**`.

This `char const**` will be valid while both `vec` and `arr` are valid.

Removing `const` is possible if your api actually will obey `const` but does not support it by a `const_cast` at any number of spots (ie, if you have a legacy API that wants an actual `char**`, you can `const_cast` the `data()` call to that I suspect).

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<const char*> arg( strvect.size() );
for( std:: size_t i=0; i < arg. size(); ++i)
{
  arg[i] = strvect[i].c_str();
}
```

Then use &arg[0].