# with std::transform, better to use begin() or back_inserter()?

Tags: c++

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) uses `begin()` while [this one and many others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19326729/3758484) suggest using `std::back_inserter`. I have been reading about this for an hour now and can't find any solid reason to use one over the other, or what the difference is. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: They do completely different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those do completely different things:

```
std::string a = "12345", b = "67890", c = b;

std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), [](char ch) { return ch; });
// b is now "12345"

std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(c), [](char ch) { return ch; });
// c is now "6789012345"
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the first can easily result in UB if b is smaller than a, whereas second is safe.